# Запрос на сравнение логина и пароля

Tags: c#, sql

Всем привет, помогите сделать правильный запрос к БД, чтобы он сравнивал, что логин и пароль введены правильно. У меня есть код.

```
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM t_user WHERE pass =" + pass + "and username=" + username;
```

Но он не работает :(

Вот сама БД

[image]

Comment: что значит не работает? валится с ошибкой? попробуйте в конце добавить + ";"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В кавычки нужно логин и пароль подставлять и слово and отделить от пароля... Т.е.

```
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM t_user WHERE pass = '" + pass + "' and username= '" + username +"'";
```

А вообще на будущее выводите переменную `cmd.CommandText` куда-нибудь на экран и если не увидите ошибки синтаксической, то скопируйте этот запрос например в консоль MySql и она скажет все за вас...

Comment: А можете ещё сказать как можно программно увеличить значение колонки balance, на то значение которое будет указано в переменной(в программе)? Вот например

    int balance = 5;
    cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE t_user SET balance+" + balance + ";";

Вот как-то так.

Comment: Все правильно, но только ну совсем немножко сложнее ))
 
    UPDATE `t_user` SET `balance` = `balance` + 5 WHERE `ID` = 1

SQL очень простой язык, если в нем разобраться...
Напишите, как Ваша RPG будет готова, если не забудете ) Хоть посмотрю ))) g-alex91&мэйл.ру

Comment: Спасибо :) Но это не игра.. это просто БД с таким названием, я хочу сделать авто-сёрфинг =) Но если не забуду напишу...

Comment: А можно в C#? :)

Comment: и не забывайте про малыша [Бобби Тэйблса](http://xkcd.com/327/) )